# In Swagger openapi v3.0.0, facing issue in multiple file uploads

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Trying to upload multiple files in swagger api. While uploading single file with

```
files:
    type: string
    format: binary
```

Getting file in **req.files**, but when trying for multiple files with

```
files:
   type: array
    items:
      type: string
      format: binary
```

**req.files** = null  and there is **files: '[object file],[object file]'**  in **req.body**

using nodejs with express

Answer (score 1):

Uploading an array of files is supported in Swagger UI 3.26.0+ and Swagger Editor 3.10.0+. You need to upgrade your Swagger UI to the latest version.

Earlier versions [had an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4600) where the string `[object file],[object file]` was sent instead of the actual files.