# Swagger OpenAPI3 POST Array of images and media file together

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi, connexion

I am using the swagger python-flask framework to create an OpenAPI 3 API which needs to do the following:

```
1. Upload a video file

2. Upload an array of images

3. Upload extra string data.
```

I can successfully  upload a single file successfully using:

```
MyFileUploadAPI:
 post:
  operationId: my_file_upload
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/videofile'

components:
  schemas:    
    videofile:
      type: object
      properties:
        upload:
         type: string
         format: binary


# This works fine
def my_file_upload(videofile):  
    file_name = videofile.filename
```

And I can upload an array of images and other data using:

```
MyMultipleImagesUploadAPI:
 post:
  operationId: multiple_files
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/multiplefiles'
components:
  schemas:    
    multiplefiles:
      type: object
      properties:
        Images:
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyImage'
        TotalCount:
          type: integer

# This works fine
def multiple_files(body):    

    if connexion.request.is_json:
        body = multiplefiles.from_dict(connexion.request.get_json())                
        images = body._images
        count = body._totalcount
```

Now I wish to combine the two together (Video upload + Multiple images + extra data)
So I have did the following:

```
/MyEverythingAPI:
post:
  operationId: video_multiple_images
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/everything'

components:
  schemas:  
  everything:
    type: object
    properties:
      Video:
        type: string
        format: binary
      Images:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyImage'
      TotalCount:
        type: integer

# This has issues
def video_multiple_images(body, video_clip, **kwargs): 
   #body = {'images': ['[object File]'], 'totalcount': 2}
   uploaded_file_name = video_clip.filename
```

Now there are 2 issues that I see that are just not correct:

**Issue 1.**
The video_clip was not getting passed through to the function **video_multiple_images**.
I debugged and tracked it down and saw that it was not getting added because there were no **kwargs added to my function signature. When I added this then the video file started to get passed through.
This post helped me solve that part: https://github.com/zalando/connexion/pull/753/files
I can live with this issue but would like to know why this is the case.

**Issue 2.**
The image array is coming through as [object File]''[Object File]'' etc.  This post indicates that this is not supported in OpenAPI 3: [In Swagger openapi v3.0.0, facing issue in multiple file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192698/in-swagger-openapi-v3-0-0-facing-issue-in-multiple-file-uploads)

So how can I pass a video file + an array of images?

Comment: Your "issue 2" is just an issue with Swagger UI, not with OpenAPI. So you shouldn't have any issues when POSTing to this endpoint from your frontend or with Postman, etc. Are you specifically asking how to get this working with Swagger UI?